# not getting expected result in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

not getting expected values in y axis ,is there any problem in my code ?
[plot i m getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od29E.jpg),
[plot expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbkk9.jpg)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_values = list(range(1,1001))

y_values = [ x**2 for x in x_values]
plt.scatter(x_values,y_values,s=40)

plt.title("scattered squares 2",fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel("value",fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("square of value",fontsize=15)
# Set the range for each axis.
plt.axis([0,1100,0,1100000])
plt.show()
```

not getting expected values in y axis ,is there any problem in my code ?

Comment: what do you expect?

Comment: images added. you can see now

Comment: @py_kumar maybe upgrade your matplotlib to latest version. I'm not getting scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

using plot is much cleanrer :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_values = list(range(1,1001))

y_values = [ x**2 for x in x_values]

plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain') #< ---- here
plt.title("scattered squares 2",fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel("value",fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("square of value",fontsize=15)
# Set the range for each axis.
plt.plot(x_values,y_values)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Why this was downvoted ? Using plot makes the graph looks clearer than axis

Comment: I didn't downvote but I guess someone saw this answer as similar to mine that's why.

Comment: @Pygirl its similar , but using axis makes the graph looks thicker , ploot makes it look more cleaner

Comment: If the question is answered through other answer then suggestion related to improvement can be made to other answer via comment :)

Comment: Sure  will do that

Answer (score 0):

Use `plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')` to disable scientific notation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_values = list(range(1,1001))

y_values = [ x**2 for x in x_values]
plt.scatter(x_values,y_values,s=40)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain') #< ---- here
plt.title("scattered squares 2",fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel("value",fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("square of value",fontsize=15)
# Set the range for each axis.
plt.axis([0,1100,0,1100000])

plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: working now, is this required in every code ?

Comment: plt is used for a current plot so I guess yes but I think there will be a way to make it for everyplot without reusing the same.